# What are the user/login's required permissions for MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion in Azure SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

**My question:** What are the required (both server and database) permissions to perform a MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initialization?

**Problem Context:**

I have an Azure SQL database and an Azure App Service that connects to it.  I want the App Service to use a [database contained user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable) to maximize database flexibility and minimize security attack surface.

My code uses EF6 Code First with Migrations and I want to allow my DEV (in Azure) environment to use the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion database initializer.

I can connect to the database in question as the user and run queries using a Visual Studio or SSMS session so I know the user has access (firewall rules are alos in place).

However, when I try to run anything with the DbInitializer (both the app service and a console program) I always get "Login failed for user 'my-user'"

I have since created a server LOGIN for the user and granted the login dbmanager access, after that the initializer worked, great! *see question at top of post*

**Update:**

This isn't the answer I was looking for, this might be more permissions than required, but I want to provide detail of how I got my code working.

1. Create a login at the server level
2. Create a user for the login in the master database
3. Add the user to the dbmanager role in the master database
4. Create a user for the login in the target database
5. Add the user, in the target database, to the db_owner role

```
-- Connect to master  
CREATE LOGIN a_database_login WITH PASSWORD = 'complex_password';  
CREATE USER a_user FOR LOGIN a_database_login;  
ALTER ROLE dbmanager ADD MEMBER a_user;  

-- Connect to 'target' database  
CREATE USER a_user FOR LOGIN a_database_login;  
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'a_user';
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you need firstly grant the enough permissions to the right user.

I suggest you could firstly locate the right the database and grant the enough permissions.

You need grant CONNECT,CREATE TABLE,SELECT, REFERENCES ,INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE permission to the database contained user account.

More details, you could refer to below query.

```
GRANT CONNECT TO {username}  
--The ALL permission is deprecated and maintained only for compatibility. It DOES NOT imply ALL permissions defined on the entity.
GRANT ALL TO  {username}  
GRANT SELECT, REFERENCES ,INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO {username}
```

---

Update:

You could also try below query.

```
Use brandotestsql

CREATE USER test5 WITH PASSWORD = 'aaaa12356!';

ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER test5
```

With this connectionstring:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:yourazuresqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=brandotestsql;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=test5;Password=aaaa12356!;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Besides, I suggest you could also check you have direct the right connectionstring in your dbcontext class.

---

> The question I am asking is to clarify the actual required permissions. That way I will be able to restrict the user to the least amount of privilege (which is good security practice).

The permissions is according to the query EF will used in your application.

Firstly, you need enable connect permission.

Secondly, if you want to create table using EF, you need enable CREATE TABLE permission.

Thirdly, if you want to create delete update and insert data, you need to enable them. Normally, we will just enable one SCHEMA "dbo".

So I suggest you could enable below permissions.

```
CONNECT
CREATE TABLE 
SELECT, REFERENCES ,INSERT,ALTER, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA :: dbo
```

Comment: Actual my user was a member of the db_owner role so (my understanding) they should have had full access to the database in question.  Nevertheless, I still get the login failed error

Comment: I have also test with a new user with dbb_owner role[ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER test3], I could perform MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initialization well. I suggest you could check the connection string to make sure the user name and password is right and try again. I suggest you could also make sure  you have enable the right IP address in the azure sql firewall.

Comment: I have actually got a working version of my code.  The question I am asking is to clarify the actual required permissions.  That way I will be able to restrict the user to the least amount of privilege (which is good security practice).

Comment: Update the answer.

Comment: But no one has provided an answer.  I think you are misunderstanding my question.  I want to know what the required level of permission is to run a MigrateToLatestVersion database initializer.  Something along the lines of server roles = dbcreator & loginmanager and database roles = "db_owner" or a bunch of GRANT statements.  Or a link to that information

Comment: In my opinion, EF is a tool which will generate the sql query according to your codes. No matter you run a MigrateToLatestVersion database initializer or run SQL SP. The permission is according to how to want to use EF to manage your database. In my test demo, I just create some table in the seed memthod when using MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initialization. I provide the enough permissions. Normally we could add the all permission to the specific SCHEMA like dbo.Because EF could create drop table and manage all the data in the table.

Comment: Besides, I think we just grant the enough permission to the  database contained user. We don't need to grant the role to the user again.

Comment: Like I said, you don't understand my question